# How to give custom error if an input is not a digit?

Tags: python, if-statement

How would I make it so I can give an error like "Answer not recognised" if the answer to my input is not of `int` type?

I have already tried to incorporate things like `.isdigit()` in my `if` statement along with a few others.

I apologize for a large amount of code here - but I am required to post the entire function.

I have added a comment on top of the else statement to which I am referring to. (When trying `.isdigit()` I changed to an `elif`).

```
def rating_system():
    rate = input(
        "\nWould you like to rate your experience with MealMatcher? (y/n) ")

    if rate in ["yes", "y", "yeah"]:
        star = int(
            input("How would you rate our service on a scale of 1 to 10? "))

        if star in range(0, 11):
            os.system(clear)
            confirmation = input(
                f"Thank you for your rating! | You gave our service {star} stars out of 10, is that correct? (y/n) ")
            if confirmation in ["yes", "y", "yeah"]:
                os.system(clear)
                close = input(
                    "Thank you for using MealMatcher! Would you like to close? (y/n)")
                if close in ["yes", "y", "yeah"]:
                    os.system(clear)
                    print(
                        "Closing Application... | Thank you for using MealMatcher" * 3)
                    raise SystemExit
                elif close in ["no", "n", "nope"]:
                    os.system(clear)
                    print("Well you have to...")
                    print("*kicks out*")
                    print(
                        "\x1B[3m" + "User in your channel was banned from the server." + "\x1B[0m")
                    raise SystemExit
                else:
                    os.system(clear)
                    print("Answer Invalid")
            elif confirmation in ["no", "n", "nope"]:
                os.system(clear)
                print("Retrying Statement... \n")
                rating_system()
            else:
                os.system(clear)
                print("Answer Invalid")
                rating_system()
        elif star not in range(0, 11):
            os.system(clear)
            print("That is not a valid answer | Try again: \n")
            rating_system()
            # Referring to the below else statement:
            else:
                os.system(clear)
                print("Answer not Recognised.")
                rating_system()
        elif rate in ["no", "n", "nope"]:
            os.system(clear)
            print("Closing Application | Thank you for your time. \n" * 3)
            raise SystemExit
        else:
            os.system(clear)
            print("Answer Invalid \n")
            rating_system()
```

Comment: there is no if for that else statement. indentation is right ?

Comment: In your code you convert any input to `int` right after getting it from the user, so in any case the user wouldn't insert an `int` you will get `ValueError` excpetion with message: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: `

Answer (score 1):

Base on your code to check if `star` is `int` modifiy your code as follow:

```
try:
    star = int(input("How would you rate our service on a scale of 1 to 10? "))
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid input, please use numbers only!")
    # re-reun your function
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do it like this

```py
inp = input("Enter input: ")
if type(inp) != int:
    print("Answer not recognized")
```

Comment: The type of the input will be a string even if only numbers were typed. You need to `int()` it and see if that fails or not.

Comment: Thank you! I will also make sure to try this out.